# Installed Brother printer not on printer list

Tags: printing

I recently tried to install a Brother HL-2270DW printer.  The printer appeared to have installed successfully, including successfully printing a test page. However, the printer does not show on the list of installed printers when I attempt to print from any application.
Sorry to ask such a simple question, but I'm new to Linux and don't know what to do next.
thank you.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using?